# FTP: Speed of moving files from one directory to another

Tags: ftp

Okay, apologies for the very amateurish question here. I've got a 5GB folder `images` that I will soon be moving from `/uploads` to `/archives/2011/uploads` (i.e. another directory on the same server). If I do this by FTP (in a GUI client), can this move be done instantaneously or will it take hours for the files to go across?

Comment: FXP can do remote transfers. Your FTP server might not support it though. SSH into box if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply rename the remote folder from `/uploads` to `/archives/2011/uploads`.